# Socket.io v1.x not working on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I had a simple chat app built with express and socket.io (v0.9.x) which was working on Heroku. Now that I updated to socket.io 1.3.5, however, the chat functionality is no longer working.

I have the server configured as follows

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Then in the client (I downloaded the actual socket.io.js file)

```
script(src='/javascripts/socket.io.js', type='text/javascript')
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```

One thing I notice is that when I run the app locally, if I open the dev console and type `socket` it returns the socket.io code, but when it's running on Heroku it just says `Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined`, could this be part of my issue?

---

**UPDATE:** In response to jfriend00's comment I changed the code on the client back to what it was, shown below, but it has made no difference

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js', type='text/javascript')
var socket = io.connect();
```

Also, no errors are showing, but there is also no notification to say `socket.io` started which I was seeing before (don't know if it's deprecated in the newer version, or a sign of a fault)

Comment: Do you have matching versions of socket.io for client and server?  Any errors showing in server console or client console?  The 1.x doc says to just do `io()` in the client to connect to the current page's domain and the default namespace.

Comment: did you solve this issues????